# How to make Horizontal scroll segment in swift

Tags: swift, uikit

when we scroll segment horizontally then the segment and regarding viewcontroller should scroll move horizontally

for that i have tried [SJSegmentedScrollView](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SJSegmentedScrollView)

i have installed cocoapod and added below code:

code: but here even segment not coming.. where i am mistake.. how to add segment and viewcontrollers horizontally

or is there any other thirdparty library for segment please do help here

```
import UIKit
import SJSegmentedScrollView

class SegmentViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    if let storyboard = self.storyboard {

    let headerViewController = storyboard
        .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SegmentViewController")

    let firstViewController = storyboard
        .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstTableViewController")
    firstViewController.title = "First"

    let secondViewController = storyboard
        .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondTableViewController")
    secondViewController.title = "Second"

    let thirdViewController = storyboard
        .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdTableViewController")
    thirdViewController.title = "Third"
        self.present(thirdViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        let segmentedViewController = SJSegmentedViewController(headerViewController: headerViewController,
        segmentControllers: [firstViewController,
            secondViewController,
            thirdViewController])
            
            addChild(segmentedViewController)
            self.view.addSubview(segmentedViewController.view)
            segmentedViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            segmentedViewController.didMove(toParent: self)

    
    }
    
}
}
```

Comment: appreciated if you make my answer as "accepted"

Answer (score 1):

I think no need to the using third party frameworks for every development. Try native ways first. For example you can do something like this by using **UIKit**, UISegmentedControl [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
  @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
  @IBAction func segmentedControlPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0: textLabel.text = "First";
    case 1: textLabel.text = "Second";
    case 2: textLabel.text = "Third";
    default: break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where to place textlabel

Comment: i have added segment but where to place textlabel

Comment: can u pls explain me indetails about the answer

Comment: there are 3 segment ok ? when someone press first segment that means textLabel will write First
if someone press second it will write Second and same for Third

Comment: you can place textlabel wherever you want.  it indicates that which segment on